# Horizontal page-break-inside?

Tags: html, css, printing

I have a very wide `<div>` scaled in mm.

It's something around 1000mm wide (3-4 pages wide, each 210mm wide).

The browser automatically scales everything so that its width  fits inside one page, but I want it to be broken up over multiple pages horizontally.

```
———————————————————— actual content width
———— page width

———— current printed content (squished)
———— page width

———— ———— ———— ———— ———— desired printed content (spread)
———— page width
```

I've tried using `page-break-inside: auto`, but it seems that it works only for vertical page breaks.

Is there any way I can do this (using CSS, plain HTML, or maybe even JS)? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although there ARE a lot of options for page size etc. (see http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-page/), horizontal page breaks don't seem to be possible.

However, you could go for an approach similar to responsive design in the `@print`  section of your stylesheet: Try to organize your `display`, `float` and similar parameters in a way that they appear horizontally on the screen, but vertically in the print styles.

Comment: That's a great idea! I'll try the RWD suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether you're looking for something like this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dreamster/jzub1ofc/).

I've used `div` and `span`; and used `:before` and `:after` pseudo-classes

Edit: If you want the line to be visible only on the left, remove `:after`

Comment: No, sorry, that's not what I was looking for. I was looking for a solution like @Johannes' with formatted *print*. Thanks anyways.